# Quadratic equation without math's library

Tags: c++

I have a problem, the principal function is the `case 8` of a switch statement, which should solve an equation using the Quadratic formula.

```
case 8: {
        float h, numero;
        float s = 0.00001, x = s;
        float c, q;
        cout<<"Introduce los valores: " <<endl;
        cout<<"a = "; cin>>a; cout<<endl;
        cout<<"b = "; cin>>b; cout<<endl;
        cout<<"c = "; cin>>c; cout<<endl;

        for(int e=0; e < 15; e++){
        cout<<".";
        Sleep(60);
    }

        cout<<"x = (-b +/- sqrtb^2 - 4ac)/2a "<<endl;

        q = (b*b - 4*a*c);
        if (q > 0){

            for (h=1; h <= q; h++){


                while (x*x < h){
                x += s; 
                }


            }
            cout<<"Las raices de tu ecuacion de segundo grado son: " <<endl <<(-b + q)/2*a <<endl <<" y " <<endl <<(-b - q)/2*a;
        }



        else {
            cout<<"tus raices son imaginarias :( "<<endl;
        }
    }break;
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You can also look at [Fast Inverse Square Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your exact issue is and I will edit this if you add some clarification, but here is some information and an observation that will hopefully help you.

The square root function is often implemented as an ***iterative function***, meaning that it starts at some base guess and then continuously improves on its guess with each loop. When its approximation reaches an error which is within some level of tolerance, it quits and returns its approximation.

Your code is attempting to do that, but you have a critical error within your iteration. The result is that your answer is very inaccurate compared to the standard square root implementation for the C++ math library.

```
    if (q > 0){
        for (h=1; h <= q; h++){
            while (x*x < h){
            x += s; 
            }
        }
    }
```

You have the while loop wrapped inside of a for loop that adds one and then iterates until h is greater than q. The issue is that q can represent something like `2.56`, while h only takes on the values `1.0`, `2.0`, `3.0`, etc. This adds some additional and unnecessary errors since h cannot actually represent the true value of q, so the loop has to make due with approximating `2.0` instead of `2.56`.

You can achieve accuracy that is very close to C++'s sqrt function if you change it to:

```
if (q > 0){
    while (x*x < q){
        x += s; 
    }
}
```

Notice that I have removed the for loop and changed `while (x*x < h)` to `while (x*x < q)`.

I hope this helps. Please post more details if this was not what you were looking for!

Comment: the problem is that i've done the same thing in the case 5 and it works: